# Recording all types of audio calls on Android

Tags: android, audio-recording

Is there software that records all my audio calls on Android automatically? The cellular calls, WhatsApp calls, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I believe call recording depends on type of phone and android version. So it may be difficult to find one app that does all. However, you can try these out on your phone e.g.

- [App Call Recorder](https://apkpure.com/app-call-recorder/com.sparklingapps.callrecorder) is meant to do whatsapp for some phones...
- [Call Recorder](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.github.axet.callrecorder/) - a Simple call recorder, no ads, open-source